# ado.net - is putting a single SQL statement through a connection better than equivalent multiple SQL statements?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlconnection

Assuming the following code:

```
public void ExecuteSomeSql(string sql, SqlConnection sqlConnection)
{
  etc etc
}
```

And assuming `allSql` = `sql1` + `sql2` + `sql3`.

Is there any difference in performance or anything else between:

**Scenario 1**

```
ExecuteSomeSql(allSql, sqlConnection);
```

and

**Scenario 2**

```
ExecuteSomeSql(sql1, sqlConnection);
ExecuteSomeSql(sql2, sqlConnection);
ExecuteSomeSql(sql3, sqlConnection);
```

I'm not really sure what's done when SQL is executed through the **same** connection multiple times. Presumably there's no complicated handshake since we already have an active connection.

Is there any strong reason I should prefer Scenario 1 over Scenario 2?

(For context, my question is really driving at whether I can implement some business rules in C#, which I would prefer to do, or whether (performance being important) I should try to execute everything in a single SQL command.)

Comment: I'm 2 days into a bug fix due to performance issues caused by `Scenario 2`. Setting up a call to the db and parsing the result is expensive. So I try and do as much as possible once there

Comment: On the whole executing one block of SQL with one connection will be faster than executing several blocks with several connections.  Whether this makes any practical difference to anything depends on a million variables.  Far more importantly try not to pass text into SQL server to be directly executed, use stored procedures where you can.  If you don't use SPs MAKE SURE you use params.

Comment: Interesting. So parameterisation is important to performance as well as security? Is that because of execution plan caching?

Comment: yes and parameterization prevents SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to a large extent it depends on the operation you're carrying out. If you're inserting 1 record, it's not going to make a huge amount of difference what you do (but you should use parameterized queries for security and allow the exec plan to be cached). If you're inserting 10 records, you could do that by sending one string of sql containing 10 statements separated by semicolons but you wouldnt be able to use parameters (or if you did you'd need 10x parameters where x is the number of fields you're inserting), so you'd be better off going for a parameterized query. If you had 100 inserts to make you really should use a parameterized query. If you had 1000 inserts to make, you should probably use the SqlBulkCopy class

All in, there's never really any good reason not to use parameterized statements. Even people who argue against using them "because the sql is dynamic" - you can surely build a parameterized SQL string and populate a parameters collection in a loop just as well as you can concatenate strings together..

If you're looking for a way to make your SQL more performant you'll need to post more about the contents of the SQL in your example. If it is inserting a single char into a single column a million times then undoubtedly using one parameterized query where you write the SQL, add the parameter, Execute the query, then (change the parameter value and re-execute) a further 999999 times will undoubtedly be faster than setting the SqlCommandText a million times and upon every execute, sending the text to the server again. You'd probably never get the server to accept a 30+ megabyte string containing a million concatenated "insert into a(a) values('a');" statements which is the ridiculous extreme equivalent of the original question's string concat *sql1 + sql2 ... + sql1000000*

To solve the problem being queried (rather than answer the question being asked) use either parameterized queries, build the query and param collection once, change the parameter values however N number of times needed.. OR.. if your operation is truly bulk, use the classes optimized for that (e.g. SqlBulkCopy)

If your sql1, 2 and 3 are all different types of operation, prepare 3 statements, and change and execute them the number of times necessary in the client. The only time you'd really look to use multiple statements per SqlCommandText is for stuff like "INSERT INTO... SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()" to retrieve the calculated values such as autonumbers